# How to delete string from another string position in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have two string:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
//give me :
//url = http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx?tabindex=2&tabid=15
```

And:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
//give me:
//path = /TESTERS/Default6.aspx
```

Now I want to get the string:

```
http://localhost:1302
```

So what I am thinking of is I will find the position of path in url and remove the sub-string from this position in url.
What I tried:

```
string strApp = url.Remove(url.First(path));
```

or

```
string strApp = url.Remove(url.find_first_of(path));
```

but I can't find the write way to express this idea. How can I archive my goal?

Comment: Note that answer that provides correct handling of all sorts of urls is "use `UriBuilder`", so see if you get one later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you want the URL, from the start up to the beginning of your path.

You don't need to "remove" that part, only take characters up to that precise point. First, you can get that location with a simple `IndexOf` as it returns the position of the first character that matches your string. After this, simply take the part of `url` that goes from `0` to that index with `Substring`.

```
string url = "http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx?tabindex=2&tabid=15";
string path = "/TESTERS/Default6.aspx";
int indexOfPath = url.IndexOf(path);
string strApp = url.Substring(0, indexOfPath); // gives http://localhost:1302
```

Which you can shorten to

```
string strApp = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do something like below code to get the Host of URI

`Uri uri =HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri ;
string host = uri.Authority; // "example.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option.. this doesn't require any string manipulation:

```
new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, "/").AbsoluteUri
```

It generates a new Uri which is the path "/" relative to the original Url

Answer (score 0):

You should just use this instead:

```
string baseURL = HttpContext.Current.Context.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" +
      HttpContext.Current.Context.Request.Url.Authority;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be solved using string manipulation. `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` returns an [Uri object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri) which has capabilities to return the information you request.

```
var requestUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
var result = requestUrl.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer,
                                      UriFormat.Unescaped);
// result = "http://localhost:1302"
```